# Using Google login with phonegap to get user info

Tags: android, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I am using PhoneGap to create an app and would like users to sign in to their google accounts and then pull information like their name and email from their profile. Is this at all possible to do? I have found a way for users to login, but I can't figure out a way to get the information. This should be able to work on any device that has the app (mainly android and ios). Any tips would be helpful as I do not know where to begin with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the successful login action get the access token and pass the access token to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=retrieved_access_token
you will get a json output as

```
{
  "id": "xx",
  "name": "xx",
  "given_name": "xx",
  "family_name": "xx",
  "link": "xx",
  "picture": "xx",
  "gender": "xx",
  "locale": "xx"
}
```